# AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.community' has no attribute 'girvan_newman'

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx

I am trying to use networkx to do community analysis.

The error I am getting is `module 'networkx.algorithms.community' has no attribute 'girvan_newman'`.
My python version is 3.6, with networkx version 2.0.

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import community
G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)
communities_generator = community.girvan_newman(G)
top_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
next_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
sorted(map(sorted, next_level_communities))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [function you're looking for](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.centrality.girvan_newman.html) is in a slightly different namespace from what you have. You'll need to import it as follows:

```
from networkx.algorithms.community.centrality import girvan_newman
```

Note the `centrality` part of the namespace that was missing.

Comment: i imported it as you mentioned but the error is still remains

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your networkx:

```
pip install --upgrade networkx
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```py
from networkx.algorithms.community.centrality import girvan_newman
communities_generator = community.centrality.girvan_newman(G)
```

EDIT: by importing community.centrality.girvan_newman(G) instead of community.girvan_newman(G) is the key here

Comment: It's better to add some description, why old code is wrong and why your code is right